# "bxslider jquery" change the slide mode at specified width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, bxslider

like the title i'm using bxslider at my website, actually i'm using vertical thumbnail slide now, but the problem is, it's look ugly when at mobile width, so i want to change it like normal slider with arrow. can you help me how to do that? here is the things i want:
1. at normal using vertical thumb slide
2. when the width triggered at specify width, the thumb is hide (maybe display none at css)
3. Do destroyslider for stopping the vertical thumb slider and change it to normal slider with arrow
4. when the width is normal again, it will switch again to vertical thumb slider

ok here is my jquery:

```
var mainImage;
$(window).load(function() {
    mainImage = $('.product-gallery').bxSlider({
        infiniteLoop: false,
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        pager: false,
        controls: false,
        auto: false,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 1,
        moveSlides: 1,
        mode: 'fade',
        adaptiveHeight: true
    });

    $('.product-gallery-thumbs ul').bxSlider({
        infiniteLoop: false,
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        pager: false,
        auto: false,
        minSlides: 4,
        maxSlides: 4,
        moveSlides: 1,
        slideWidth: '100%',
        mode: "#{options['product_thumbnail_direction']}",
        slideMargin: 10,
        onSliderLoad: function(currentIndex) {
            $('.product-gallery-thumbs ul li').eq(0).addClass('active')
        }
    });

    $('.product-gallery-thumbs ul li').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            mainImage.goToSlide($(this).index());
        });
    });
});
```

when do destroy :

```
mainImage.destroySlider();
```

here is normal slider with arrow:

```
mainImage.bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: true,
    slideWidth: 600
  });
```

**UPDATE :**
I try to did this, when do destroy is work, but when switching to normal arrow slider it doesn't work. Hope you guys can help me fix this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            setMaxWidth(767px);
            mainImage.destroySlider();

            function setMaxWidth(767px) {
              mainImage.bxSlider({
                mode: 'fade',
                captions: true,
                slideWidth: 600
              });
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### bx.reloadSlider() Method

The method `destroySlider()` returns bxSlider as it was initially so don't use it if you want to change bxSlider after a reload, instead use `reloadSlider()`. Besides the obvious (reloading bxSlider), you can load a different set of options. **Note:** There are 2 Object Literals:

`var` **cfgA** `= {...}` and `var` **cfgB** `= {...}`

Each of them has key/value pairs (or properties) that are from the [bxSlider API](https://bxslider.com/options/). When calling `.bxSlider()`, simply load one of configurations:

`var bx = $('.bx').bxSlider(`**cfgA**`);`

#### onSliderResize Callback

As far as slider plugins go, bxSlider isn't the most stable and it can get buggy as browsers update and bxSlider stagnates at v.4.2.12, but there's one thing bxSlider excels in is callbacks. I've written complex programs that are controlled by bxSlider callbacks because they are reliable and never break. In this demo `onSliderResize` call the function `reloadBX(currentIndex)`. **Note: ** the absence of parenthesis on `reloadBX()`:

`onSliderResize:` **reloadBX**

#### reloadBX(currentIndex)

This is the heart of the Demo. For demonstration purposes I've bound the function to a convenient button. When testing the Demo, you should expect the following by either clicking the <kbd>RELOAD</kbd> button, or resizing bxSlider:

- Toggling between `cfgA` and `cfgB`
- Relocates to the position index bxSlider was on before the reload.
- Shifts images to adjust at reload to avoid images being stuck halfway.

---

**Details commented in Demo**

#### Demo

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>bxSlider Reload</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
  <style>
    img {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button class='reload'>RELOAD</button>
  <ul class='bx'>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/DrEwPH0.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MEPxbq4.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6qGdA1e.gif">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src='https://i.imgur.com/DsM6J8U.gif'>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sbxyLKX.png">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/DheohWR.gif">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Cfg flag
    var AB = 'A';

    // Index counter
    var idx = 0;

    // cfgA
    var cfgA = {
      mode: 'horizontal',
      slideWidth: 320,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      onSliderResize: reloadBX
    };

    // cfgB
    var cfgB = {
      mode: 'fade',
      captions: true,
      slideWidth: 160,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      onSliderResize: reloadBX
    };

    // Reference bxSlider instance
    var bx = $('.bx').bxSlider(cfgA);

    /*
    Resize Callback 
    */ // Called on resize event
    function reloadBX(current) {

      // Store current index
      idx = current;

      // Determine what configuration bx is in
      if (AB === "A") {

        /* if bx is in cfgA...
        || reload slider with cfgB
        */
        bx.reloadSlider(cfgB);

        // Shift all img to the left
        $('img').css('transform', 'translateX(-25%)');

        // Switch cfg flag to B
        AB = "B";

        // Otherwise...
      } else {

        // Reload slider with cfgA
        bx.reloadSlider(cfgA);

        // Shift all img to the right
        $('img').css('transform', 'translateX(0)');

        // Switch cfg flag to A
        AB = "A";
      }

      // Go back to the index before reload
      bx.goToSlide(idx);
    }

    // Added a reload button for convenient testing 
    $('.reload').click(function(e) {

      // Get the current index and store it
      idx = bx.getCurrentSlide();

      /* Need to use the .call() function so that the context
      || is changed to bxSlider
      */
      reloadBX.call(this, idx);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```